# How to edit Hamburger Menu items list at runtime?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, template10

I'm using Template 10 in my UWP application. However I need to Enable/Disable the hamburger buttons according to my conditions.
I'm setting `IsFullScreen` property to true initially because I want to show the hamburger menu after user logs in the application.
Because the Shell page is loaded initially then at runtime if I create a new instance of it then the application is running on full screen and I'm unable to see the Menu.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: The `HamburgerButtonInfo` has a `IsEnabled` property, you could bind this property to your ViewModel's someone property to control its 'Enable/Disable' status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Accessing Shell page instance

You will first need to be able to access the `Shell` page instance. You can do this in two ways. If you know, there will always be a single instance, you can add a `static` property pointing to it like this:

```
public static Shell Instance { get; private set; }
```

And set the instance in the constructor:

```
public Shell()
{
    //InitializeComponent(), etc....
    Instance = this;
}
```

Now from anywhere, you can use `Shell.Instance` to access it. If you could theoretically have multiple windows, you can access the instance of current `Shell` using `Windows.Current.Content`. If you used the Template 10 Hamburger template, you would do:

```
var dialog = (ModalDialog)Window.Current.Content;
var shell = (Shell)dialog.Content;
```

### Disabling/enabling

The items in `HamburgerMenu` control are of type `HamburgerButtonInfo` and have an `IsEnabled` property which you can use for enabling/disabling. If you add a `x:Name="Menu"` to the `HamburgerMenu` control, you can then write a enabling method like this:

```
public void SetMenuEnabled(bool enable)
{
   foreach (var primaryButton in Menu.PrimaryButtons)
   {
      primaryButton.IsEnabled = false;
   }
   foreach (var secondaryButton in Menu.SecondaryButtons)
   {
      secondaryButton.IsEnabled = false;
   }
}
```

You can put this method in the `Shell` page and call it via `Shell.Instance.SetMenuEnabled(false)` to disable and `Shell.Instance.SetMenuEnabled(true)` to enable all buttons.